# My variable in javascript is not staying true after being called in an onclick function

Tags: javascript, if-statement, variables

I have a variable that I want to start off as false, and after an .onclick function, I want it to be toggled to true.

This is my Javascript, any help is appreciated.

The "start" variable is the one I am having trouble with, everything else shown works fine, but if there's any helpful hints related to any of it, feel free to mention them.

```
const left_button = document.getElementById("left")
const right_button = document.getElementById("right")
const start_game = document.getElementById("start-game");
const start_game_button = document.getElementById("");
const player_1_name = document.getElementById("player1");
const player_2_name = document.getElementById("player2");
const score1 = document.getElementById("score1");
const score2 = document.getElementById("score2");
var start = false;

score1.style.display = "none";
score2.style.display = "none";

start_game.onclick = function(){
    player_1_name.innerHTML = prompt("Name of Player One: ");
    player_2_name.innerHTML = prompt("Name of Player Two: ");
    start_game.style.display = "none";
    score1.style.display = "";
    score2.style.display = "";
    var start = true;
}

if (start == true) {
    left_button.onclick = function(){
        alert("test");
    }
}
```

Comment: `start_game_button` is undefined...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `start` equal to `false`:

```
var start = false;
```

Then you create a function which *won't be called until some later time*.  Then immediately check the value of `start`:

```
if (start == true) {
  left_button.onclick = function(){
    alert("test");
  }
}
```

`start` was *just defined as `false`*, so this `if` block won't execute.

Basically, you're thinking of it backwards.  You're trying to do this:

> If the value is true, define a click handler

Instead, do this:

> Define a click handler, and *within the click handler* check if the value is true

For example:

```
left_button.onclick = function(){
  if (start == true) {
    alert("test");
  }
}
```

---

Aside from that, the [other answer posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73562133/328193) also points out that you're *shadowing* the `start` variable here:

```
start_game.onclick = function(){
  //...
  var start = true;
}
```

Basically this declares an *entirely new variable* that only exists within the scope of that function and then is never used.  Don't re-declare a new variable, just assign a value to the variable you already have:

```
start_game.onclick = function(){
  //...
  start = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I am new to JavaScript and didn't know about assigning variables of the same name. Thanks for the other suggestions as well.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do `var start = true;`

This is effectively reassigning another variable named "start".

Just do `start = true;`